# Conditionally define a Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, conditional-statements, database-cursor

I have a Procedure in Oracle that takes a `varchar2` paramater.  Based on the value of that parameter, I need to define a cursor.  The cursor will operate on different tables based on the value of the parameter.

I wanted to do something like below but it throws an error in the `CURSOR` definition piece of code.  Any ideas?

```
PROCEDURE GET_RECORDS(v_action IN VARCHAR2)
IS
CURSOR get_records
IS
       IF(v_action = 'DO THIS') THEN
           SELECT * from <THIS>;
       ELSE
           SELECT * from <THAT>;
       END IF;
BEGIN
       OPEN get_records;

       FETCH get_records
       INTO v_thing;

       v_loop := 0;
       WHILE get_records%FOUND
       LOOP

           FETCH get_records
           INTO v_thing;

       END LOOP;
       CLOSE get_records;
END;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you will need a REF CURSOR and open it conditionaly, for example:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_RECORDS(v_action IN VARCHAR2) IS
  2     v_thing     VARCHAR2(10);
  3     get_records SYS_REFCURSOR;
  4  BEGIN
  5     IF (v_action = 'DO THIS') THEN
  6        OPEN get_records FOR
  7           SELECT 1 FROM dual;
  8     ELSE
  9        OPEN get_records FOR
 10           SELECT 2 FROM dual;
 11     END IF;
 12  
 13     LOOP
 14        FETCH get_records INTO v_thing;
 15        EXIT WHEN get_records%NOTFOUND;
 16        /* do things */
 17        dbms_output.put_line(v_thing);
 18     END LOOP;
 19     CLOSE get_records;
 20  END;
 21  /

Procedure created

SQL> exec get_records ('DO THIS');
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> exec get_records ('DO THAT');
2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably code something like this (where the two loops may call the same functions)

```
BEGIN
  IF( v_action = 'DO THIS' )
  THEN
    FOR this_cur IN (SELECT * FROM <THIS>)
    LOOP
      <<do something>>
    END LOOP;
  ELSE
    FOR that_cur IN (SELECT * FROM <THAT>)
    LOOP
      <<do something else>>
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
```

You could also use dynamic SQL to open the cursor but that tends to get more complicated, particularly if there are only two options.

```
IS
  get_records SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_sql_stmt  VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  IF( v_action = 'DO THIS' )
  THEN
    l_sql_stmt := 'SELECT * from <THIS>';
  ELSE
    l_sql_stmt := 'SELECT * from <THAT>';
  END IF;

  OPEN get_records FOR l_sql_stmt;
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even use the condition inside the implicit for loop. Without cursor declaration or `SYS_REFCURSOR` (I dislike them sorry) - I mean you can use your variables, here `v_action`, inside implicit cursor declaration:

```
BEGIN
    FOR this_cur IN (
       SELECT * FROM <THIS> 
        WHERE v_action = 'DO THIS'
    ) LOOP
      <<do something>>
    END LOOP;
    FOR that_cur IN (
       SELECT * FROM <THIS> 
        WHERE v_action <> 'DO THIS'
    ) LOOP
      <<do something else>>
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
```