# pl sql cursor for loop in

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two cursors the for loop should use the cursor based on the status.

```
CURSOR order_hist1 IS 
   SELECT id, ordernum, address FROM order_hist; 

CURSOR order_hist2 IS 
   SELECT id, ordernum, address FROM order_hist_complete;
```

so for loop should use cursor order_hist2 is the variable status = 'COMPLETE'
else use order_hist1

```
 FOR aDistinctLine in --     LOOP
   -- 300 lines code in this loop
 END LOOP;
```

I don't want o use REF Cursors

Comment: seems to be already answered [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864404/conditionally-define-a-cursor-in-oracle)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally define a Cursor in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864404/conditionally-define-a-cursor-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

You can use implicit for loop:

- For your case, it looks suitable to change the two cursors to a single one, using `UNION` (`UNION ALL` if you need to process duplicates, or performance reasons), like follows:

---

```
FOR aDistinctLine in (
  -- first cursor: status <> COMPLETE
  SELECT id, ordernum, address FROM order_hist 
   WHERE status <> 'COMPLETE' 
  UNION 
  SELECT id, ordernum, address FROM order_hist_complete 
   WHERE status = 'COMPLETE' 
) LOOP

-- do things with 
--     aDistinctLine.id, 
--     aDistinctLine.ordernum, 
--     aDistinctLine.address 

END LOOP;
```

Then it's better to have `status` look like a local variable, e.g. call it `l_status`; I had to convince myself it could work to use a plsql variable inside an implicit for loop... guess I learned something today!

```
declare
  l_status varchar2(8) := 'COMPLETE';
begin
  for x in (select 'realy?' val from dual where l_status = 'COMPLETE')
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(x.val);
  end loop;

  l_status := 'graby';
  for x in (select 'here: not complete' val from dual where l_status <> 'COMPLETE')
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(x.val);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Also, I think, the OP might have a table say `order` which will store the variable `status = complete`.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal - the question says `status` is a variable (though this does assume the table sin the cursor don't also have a column with that name; you can only go on what the OP tells you though). And what 2000 lines? You can still use a single explicit cursor this way if you prefer - you can even pass the status variable as as a formal argument...

Comment: @J.Chomel - I'm confused; why is the second option with the procedure necessary? The OP's original 300 lines can just go inside the single loop in your first option, surely, ...status being a variable rather than a column name doesn't make any difference, does it? (A naming convention that makes it clear it's a variable would be nice, but if there's no scope clash that's kind of cosmetic.)

Comment: @AlexPoole, eidited; I guess I'm the most confused... I didn't know it could work this way. So I was right for being twice wrong. Sp0ooky.

Comment: @user565992, `status` doesn't need to be part of the tables! See my edited answer with a snipet to test it works with a local variable.

Comment: WHY? because you can re-use it multiple times if you need and your code looks better then 100 lines of select statement

Comment: @TheName, I don't think Alex will disagree there shouldn't be 300 lines inside the loop - but that's not the most important here.

Comment: @thename, now I get it what you meant. It's useful to declare cursors in case we need you reuse them. Rarely the case in my field.

Comment: @J.Chomel I'ts the worst practise to use sql in pl/sql, because those things is the case of errors.

Comment: @TheName, I guess I understand why now... Good naming convention should save us :)

Comment: @user565992, did it help you achieve what you intended? I didn't understand why I got downvoted here.