# Oracle PL/SQL switch between raw and hierarchical select

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I need in one Oracle PL/SQL select to switch between raw select and hierarchical select statements depending on some variable. But, cannot use If statement in select.
For example, I have hierarchical statement

```
select a.*
from myTable a
start with a.id = varValue
connect by prior a.id = a.parentId
```

if some varCondition is 0.
If varCondition = 1 then select should give result the same as result of statement
 `select a.* from myTable a where a.id = varValue`
Something like `select a.* from myTable a start with a.id = varValue connect by prior a.id = decode(varCondition, ...)`

Is it possible?

Comment: there is no PL/SQL in your question. Only plain SQL. But I don't think this is possible with plain SQL. As soon as `connect by` is part of the statement it will be a recursive one. But it might indeed be possible using PL/SQL and a function that uses dynamic SQL

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I need to use sql as source of Apex Interactive Report and thought I can resolve this by using modified sql statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NULL` in the `CONNECT BY` clause to ensure it is always false when your `varCondition` variable is `1` and to use the hierarchy in other cases:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        myTable
START WITH  id = varValue
CONNECT BY  PRIOR id = DECODE( varCondition, 1, NULL, parentId )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
PROCEDURE GET_RECORDS(v_action IN VARCHAR2)
IS
CURSOR get_records
IS
       IF(v_action = 'DO THIS') THEN
           SELECT * from <THIS>;
       ELSE
           SELECT * from <THAT>;
       END IF;
BEGIN
       OPEN get_records;

       FETCH get_records
       INTO v_thing;

       v_loop := 0;
       WHILE get_records%FOUND
       LOOP

           FETCH get_records
           INTO v_thing;

       END LOOP;
       CLOSE get_records;
END;
```

(Source: [[Conditionally define a Cursor in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864404/conditionally-define-a-cursor-in-oracle]))

Or you can use this:

```
declare
   SQL_Text varchar2(32760) := 'select * from dual'; --your query goes here
   SQL_Text2 varchar2(32760) := 'select * from dual'; --your query goes here
   cur sys_refcursor;
begin
   IF some_condition THEN
     open cur for SQL_Text;
   ELSE
     open cur for SQL_Text2;
   END IF;
   -- ...
end;
```